# metronics mDatatable loading problem for huge data 40000 appx..Could not find any solution

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

metronics mDatatable does not load the table for huge data 40000 appx..so I dont know how to do server side with mdatatable as because mdatatable and datatable is different structure..Please help..

```
            var datatable = $('.m_datatable_event_administrator').mDatatable({
                // datasource definition
                data: {
                    type: 'local',
                    source: resp,
                    pageSize: 10
                },

                // layout definition
                layout: {
                    theme: 'default', // datatable theme
                    class: '', // custom wrapper class
                    scroll: false, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
                    // height: 450, // datatable's body's fixed height
                    footer: false // display/hide footer
                },

                // column sorting
                sortable: true,

                pagination: true,

                search: {
                    input: $('#search_event_administrator')
                },
```

Comment: Please share the code and more details.

Comment: I have edited some codes..Please check.its working for 50 to 100 datas..but its stuck when I load 40000 datas.

Comment: Loading 40000 data row is not a good practice. You can use server-side like `serverPaging: true,serverFiltering: true,serverSorting: true`. Read [this](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=datatable) doc for more details.